# Get the folder name of a files parent

Tags: java

I'm working with some code and I want it to behave differently depending on the folder name that the file is in. I don't need the absolute path just the final folder. Everything that I have seen so far is using a absolute path that is specified in the file.

Comment: I realized that I was actually trying to get the name of the package the code file was in in my project. I'm voting to delete my question so not to confuse other looking for help. I was able to get the information by passing 'this' to a string and splitting that on the '.'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
public static String getParentName(File file) {
    if(file == null || file.isDirectory()) {
            return null;
    }
    String parent = file.getParent();
    parent = parent.substring(parent.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1, parent.length());
    return parent;      
}
```

Unfortunately there is no pre-provided method that just returns the name of the last folder in the file's path, so you have to do some String manipulation to get it.

Comment: Made the method null safe... really the only way it could have thrown a null pointer was if the file itself was null, or if the parent was null... which would only be possible if the file was something like the C drive.  I'm sure there are plenty of methods in the Java API that aren't null safe.  Let me know if there's anything else I missed.

Answer (score 2):

Try [java.io.File.getParentFile()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParentFile()) method.

```
String getFileParentName(File file) {
    if (file != null && file.getParentFile() != null) {
        return file.getParentFile().getName();
    }
    return null; // no parent for file
}
```

Comment: Sorry, got interrupted.  file.getParent() returns the full path name of the parent folder, whereas TheHamstring wants only the name of the final folder.  For example, if the file is "C:\test\parent\child.txt", file.getParent() will return "C:\test\parent", whereas TheHamstring would only want "parent" returned.  In his question, TheHamstring notes that "Everything that I have seen so far is using a absolute path", so I take it he's already tried file.getParent().

Comment: @TJamesBoone is it OK now?

Answer (score 2):

I think [java.io.File.getParent()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParent%28%29) is what you are looking for:

```
import java.io.File;

public class Demo {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      File f = null;
      String parent="not found";
      f = new File("/tmp/test.txt");
      parent = f.getParent();
      System.out.print("parent name: "+v);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's

```
String File.getParent()
```

There's also

```
File File.getParentFile()
```

I don't know what the return in terms of being absolute or relative, but if it's absolute you can always find the last (or second to last, depending) instance of the "\" character (remember to escape it like this "\\") to denote where the lowest folder level is.

For example, if the function returned:

"C:\Users\YourName" is where you'd get the last occurance of "\", and all characters after it would be the folder you want

"C:\Users\YourName\" is where you'd get the second to last occurance of "\", and all characters between that and the last "\" would be the folder you're looking for.

Java File API:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Answer (score 0):

```
String path = "/abc/def"; // path to the directory  
try
{
    File folder = new File(path);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    for (File file : listOfFiles) 
    {
      if(file.isDirectory())
      {
        switch(file.getName)
        {
             case "folder1" : //do something
              break
             case "folder2" : //do something else 
              break
        }  
      }
    }
}   
catch(Exception e) 
{
      System.out.println("Directory not Found"); 
}
```